# Insertar datos en MySQL y Java en Eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas para lograr insertar correctamente los datos de mi programa a la tabla de mi base de datos.

Para conectarme a **MySQL**, tengo esto:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ConexionBD {

    // Ruta de nuestra base de datos
    private String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centralitabd";

    // Nombre de usuario de mysql
    private String username = "root";

    // Clave de usuario de mysql
    private String password = "123456789";

    // Nuestra librería mysql
    private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

    // Objeto del tipo Connection para crear la conexión
    private Connection con;

    public void Conexion()
    {
        try {
            // Cargar drivers de MySQL
            Class.forName(driver);

            // Establecer la conexion con la base de datos
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, username, password);

            System.out.println("Conexión realizada a la base de datos con éxito.");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!, conexión fallida a la base de datos.");
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con; // Retorno el objeto Connection
    }
```

Muchos dicen que use `preparedstatement`, otros dicen que es mejor `createstatement`, al final no he logrado hacer funcionar ninguno, aqui mi código:

```
public void Insertar(int ID, String Tipo, String Franja, String NumeroOrigen, String NumeroDestino, int Duracion, Double Precio) {

    // Establecer conexión con la base de datos
    ConexionBD conexion = new ConexionBD();

        // Pasamos el objeto Connection de nuestra clase "ConexionBD" a esta instancia por medio del método getConnection()
        Connection con = conexion.getConnection();

        // Crear sentencia SQL para insertar en la base de datos
        String query = "INSERT INTO llamadas (ID, Tipo, Franja, NumeroOrigen, NumeroDestino, Duracion, Precio) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            rs.setInt       (1, ID);
            rs.setString    (2, Tipo);
            rs.setString    (3, Franja);
            rs.setString    (4, NumeroOrigen);
            rs.setString    (5, NumeroDestino);
            rs.setInt       (6, Duracion);
            rs.setDouble    (7, Precio);

            // Indicamos que comience la actualización de la tabla en nuestra base de datos
            st.executeUpdate();

            // Cerramos las conexiones, en orden inverso a su apertura
            st.close();
            con.close();

            System.out.println("Llamada agregada con éxito a la base de datos.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Error!, la llamada no pudo ser agregada a la base de datos.");
        }
    }
```

Me marca error en:
`setInt`, `setString`, `executeUpdate`, etc.

Qué tengo mal?.

Cualquier ayuda sería bien recibida.

Comment: mal copy paste, lo he arreglado, espero puedas ayudarme :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Debes de usar executeUpdate para un insert,delete u update. Y se usa executeQuery para un query y los  ResultSet solo se usan para recuperar información de querys, y tu esta haciendo un insert, es decir, ResultSet no va.

Este es un ejemplo de insert con prepardstatement:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());

            // execute insert SQL stetement
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
```

Comment: una pregunta sobre el insertTableSQL, debe tener las comillas dobles y el signo de + obligatoriamente?, o puede ser esto: String query = "INSERT INTO llamadas (ID, Tipo, Franja, NumeroOrigen, NumeroDestino, Duracion, Precio) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

Comment: Puede ser exactamente como lo pones, pero debe ir en una sola linea. Yo lo puse así porque use varias lineas. Eso es solo concatenación de cadenas en diferentes lineas.

Comment: al correr el programa, me sigue marcando error en esta línea: PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);, ya no se como solucionarlo, he tratato de todo. :(

Comment: y que dice el error??

Comment: nullpointerexception, y otras cosas, aqui screenshot: http://oi68.tinypic.com/2gshp8z.jpg

Comment: no puedo ver tu imagen, esta bloqueada en mi red

Comment: el error dice: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException y luego me marca esta linea: PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

Comment: hey, estas disponible?, no logro resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InsertarDatos {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
     PreparedStatement stmt = null;

     String sDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String sURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lineadecodigo";

     try{
        Class.forName(sDriver).newInstance();    
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(sURL,"root","");

        String sISBN = "84-9815-212-7";
        String sTitulo = "Yo, Claudio";
        String sDescripcion="Supuesta autobiografía de Claudio";
        String sCategoria = "Novela Histórica";
        int idAutor = 3;

        stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO libros VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
        stmt.setString(1,sISBN);
        stmt.setInt(2,idAutor);
        stmt.setString(3,sTitulo);
        stmt.setString(4,sDescripcion);
        stmt.setString(5,sCategoria);

        int retorno = stmt.executeUpdate();
        if (retorno>0)
           System.out.println("Insertado correctamente");      

     } catch (SQLException sqle){
        System.out.println("SQLState: " 
           + sqle.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("SQLErrorCode: " 
           + sqle.getErrorCode());
        sqle.printStackTrace();
     } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     } finally {
        if (con != null) {
           try{
              stmt.close();
              con.close();
           } catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
     }           
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

public class snippet {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Connection connection = null;
    String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3390/discografia";

     String user = "root";

     String password = "";
     
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url1,user,password);
     
     System.out.println("dime un id");
     int id = sc.nextInt();
     
     System.out.println("dime un id_album");
     int id_album = sc.nextInt();
     
     System.out.println("dime un titulo");
     String titulo = sc.next();
     
     System.out.println("dime un duracion");
     int duracion = sc.nextInt();
     
     System.out.println("dime un letra");
     String letra = sc.next();
     
    
     String query = "INSERT INTO album values (?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst =connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, id);
        pst.setInt(2, id_album);
        pst.setString(3, titulo);
        pst.setInt(4, duracion);
        pst.setString(5, letra);
        
       pst.executeUpdate();
     
      
        pst.close();
     
}
```

}

}
}}

Comment: Saludos, es genial que quieras aportar, aunque seria mucho mejor si das una breve explicación de lo que hace tu código, considera que los usuarios nuevos con poca experiencia no entenderán tu respuesta, por favor lee [cómo responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), también te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y así obtener tu primera medalla. ;)