# ¿Error CRUD MySQL -Java Escritorio?

Tags: java, mysql, java-8, netbeans-8.2

Tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy creando un CRUD de edición de pacientes pero no me funciona la modificación ya que me sale error en los métodos de agregar y borrar.

Tengo un botón que cuando capta el evento, elimina el registro de la tabla de datos y posteriormente agrega el nuevo registro con los datos obtenidos en los campos de texto.

**El botón tiene lo siguiente:**

```java
private void btn_AGREGAR_PACIENTESActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                      

        //Verificacion de que los campos esten completamenete llenos
        if (    txtCEDULA_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") || 
                txtNOMBRE_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") || 
                txtAPELLIDO_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") || 
                txtCONTRASEÑA_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") || 
                txtNACIMIENTO_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") ||
                txtESTADO_PACIENTE.getText().equals("") ||
                txtENFERMEDAD_PACIENTE.getText().equals("")
                ) {
            //Aviso de que no estan llenos
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rellene todos los campos por favor");

        } else {
            //Creacion de variables para los metodos posteriores
            String cedula_nuevo=txtCEDULA_PACIENTE.getText();
            String nombre_nuevo=txtNOMBRE_PACIENTE.getText();
            String apellido_nuevo=txtAPELLIDO_PACIENTE.getText();
            String contraseña_nuevo=txtCONTRASEÑA_PACIENTE.getText();
            String nacimiento_nuevo=txtNACIMIENTO_PACIENTE.getText();
            String estado_nuevo=txtESTADO_PACIENTE.getText();
            String enfermedad_nuevo=txtENFERMEDAD_PACIENTE.getText();

            //Evalua si hay que eliminar el registro ya que se encuentra un registro existente con dicha cedula
            //Positivo (Toca borrar y luego eliminar)
            if (consultaCedula(cedula_nuevo)==true) {
                //Borrando
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entrando a borrar");
                borrarBD(Integer.parseInt(cedula_nuevo));
                //Agregando
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Agregando el registro");
                agregarBD(Integer.parseInt(cedula_nuevo), nombre_nuevo, apellido_nuevo, contraseña_nuevo, nacimiento_nuevo, estado_nuevo, enfermedad_nuevo);
            }
            //Negativo (No existe un registro con dicha cedula, por lo tanto solo basta con agregar)
            else if (consultaCedula(cedula_nuevo)==false) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Agregando el registro");
                agregarBD(Integer.parseInt(cedula_nuevo), nombre_nuevo, apellido_nuevo, contraseña_nuevo, nacimiento_nuevo, estado_nuevo, enfermedad_nuevo);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Metodo consultar(funciona)**

```java
public boolean consultaCedula(String cedula){
        //Creamos el objeto de tipo booleano para retornar
        boolean consulta=false;
        //Conectamos a la BD
            Conexion con = new Conexion();
            Connection accesoBD = con.getConnection();

            //Verificamos la existencia en BD la cédula a agregar o modificar
            String SQL_BUSQUEDA_CEDULA= "select count(*) from pacientes where cedula ="+Integer.parseInt(cedula)+";";
            int verificacionCedula=10;

            //Try-CatchVerificacion
            try {
                Statement st = accesoBD.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL_BUSQUEDA_CEDULA);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    verificacionCedula=rs.getInt(1);
                }  
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Error al buscar la cedula en la BD"+e);
                }

            //Condicional Cedula Existente
                //Si existe int igual a 1 y retorna true
                if (verificacionCedula==1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cédula existe");
                    consulta=true;
                //Si existe int igual a 0 y retorna false
                }else if (verificacionCedula==0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cédula no existe");
                    consulta=false;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "consulta resulta: "+consulta);
         return consulta;
    }
```

**Metodo borrar (problema con el statement)**

```java
public void borrarBD(int cedula_nuevo){
        //Sentecia para borrar el registro
        String SQL_BORRAR_REGISTRO="DELETE FROM `pacientes` WHERE (Cedula = "+cedula_nuevo+");";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La cedula a buscar es: "+cedula_nuevo);
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        Connection accesoBD = con.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement st=accesoBD.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(SQL_BORRAR_REGISTRO);
            while (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs);
                System.out.println("Llegue al while del borrar");
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al eliminar el usuario \n"+e);
        }
    }
```

**Metodo agregar(problema con el statement tambien)**

```java
//Agregando en la BD
        //Sentencia para agregar el nuevo registro
        String SQL_ADDPacientes = "INSERT INTO `pacientes` (`Cedula`, `Nombres`, `Apellidos`, `Contraseña`, `Fecha_Nacimiento`, `Estado`, `Enfermedad`) VALUES ("+cedula+", '"+nombres+"', '"+apellidos+"', '"+contraseña+"', '"+fecha_nacimiento+"', '"+estado+"', '"+enfermedad+"');";
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        Connection accesoBD = con.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement st = accesoBD.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(SQL_ADDPacientes);
            while (rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rs);
                System.out.println("Llegue al while del agregar");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al agregar el usuario \n"+e);
        }
    }
```

Tengo problemas con los métodos de agregar y borrar como ven creo que esta bien las `executeQuery` pero no estoy seguro, por eso vengo a ustedes para saber si notan algo raro.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el mismo problema que respondí en este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36024/3834).

Debes de usar `executeUpdate` para un `insert`,`delete` u `update`. Y se usa `executeQuery` para un `select` y los `ResultSet` solo se usan para recuperar información de querys (`select`).

**Actualización:**
Este es un ejemplo de insert con prepardstatement:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
                + "(?,?,?,?)";

        try {
            dbConnection = getDBConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            preparedStatement.setInt(1, 11);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "mkyong");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "system");
            preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp());

            // execute insert SQL stetement
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("Record is inserted into DBUSER table!");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
```

Comment: Amigo podrías indicarme cómo quedaría el código por favor! Que no conozco como sería el cambio...

Comment: Esta en el hilo que te puse, dale clic al link, ahi esta el ejemplo del código.