# CRUD, MVC, Java y SQL

Tags: java, sql

Estoy tratando de actualizar los datos de una tabla con base de datos pero no logra actualizarse sale se actualizo correctamente sin embargo no se visualizar no se en donde podría contener el error, les adjunto la imagen del mensaje espero puedan ayudarme.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No estoy muy seguro de donde pudiera estar el error ó quizás tenga que arreglar o rehacer la base datos

```
  //CRUD 
      @Override
            public Personal Read(int codper) {
                Personal per = new Personal ();
                try {
                    st = conexion.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("select idPersonal,Dni,NombrePers,ApellidoPers,Edad,Sexo,Direccion,Celular,Correo,Foto from Dpersonal where idPersonal="+codper+"");
                    rs.next();
                    per.setCodigo(rs.getInt(1));
                    per.setDNI(rs.getString(2));
                    per.setNombre(rs.getString(3));
                    per.setApellido(rs.getString(4));
                    per.setEdad(rs.getInt(5));
                    per.setSexo(rs.getString(6));
                    per.setDireccion(rs.getString(7));
                    per.setCelular(rs.getInt(8));
                    per.setCorreo(rs.getString(9));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Mensajes.MD("Error no se pueden recuperar datos"+ex);
                }
                return per;
            }
    
            @Override
            public void Update(Personal per) {
                try {
                    st = conexion.createStatement();
                    rs = st.executeQuery("update DPersonal set Dni='"+per.getDNI()+"',NombrePers='"+per.getNombre()+"',ApellidoPers='"+per.getApellido()+
                            "',Edad='"+per.getEdad()+"',Sexo='"+per.getSexo()+"',Direccion='"+per.getDireccion()+"',Celular='"+per.getCelular()+"',Correo='"+per.getCorreo()+"'"+"Where idPersonal ="+per.getCodigo());
                    
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Mensajes.MD("Se actualizaron los datos"+ex);
                }
            }
            
            
           //Controlador 
                 if (ae.getSource() == vista.btnEdit) {
                    vista.txtCodigoP1.setEditable(false);
                    int fila = vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getSelectedRow();
                    if (fila == -1) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(vista, "Debe de selecionar una fila");
                    } else {
                        int cod = Integer.parseInt((String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
                        String dni = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 2);
                        String nom = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 3);
                        String ape = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 4);
                        int ed = Integer.parseInt((String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 5).toString());
                        String s = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 6);
                        String direc = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 7);
                        int cl = Integer.parseInt((String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 8).toString());
                        String cor = (String) vista.jbtlDatosPersonal.getValueAt(fila, 9);
                        Icon f = vista.jlblFoto.getIcon();
    
                        vista.txtCodigoP1.setText("" + cod);
                        vista.txtDNIP.setText(dni);
                        vista.txtNombreP.setText(nom);
                        vista.txtApellidosP.setText(ape);
                        vista.txtEdadP.setText("" + ed);
                        vista.cboSexoP.setSelectedItem(s);
                        vista.txtDireccionP.setText(direc);
                        vista.txtCelularP.setText("" + cl);
                        vista.txtCorreoP.setText(cor);
                        vista.jlblFoto.setIcon(f);
    
                    }
                }
    
                if (ae.getSource() == vista.btnActualizar) {
                    
                    Personal per = new Personal();
                    CRUDpersonal crud = new CRUDpersonal();
                    crud.Update(per);
                    per.setDNI(vista.txtDNIP.getText());
                    per.setNombre(vista.txtNombreP.getText());
                    per.setApellido(vista.txtApellidosP.getText());
                    per.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(vista.txtEdadP.getText()));
                    per.setSexo(vista.cboSexoP.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    per.setDireccion(vista.txtDireccionP.getText());
                    per.setCelular(Integer.parseInt(vista.txtCelularP.getText()));
                    per.setCorreo(vista.txtCorreoP.getText());
                    per.setFoto(vista.jlblFoto.getIcon());
                    ListarPersonal lp = new ListarPersonal();
                    lp.MostrarPersonal(Main.ifp.jbtlDatosPersonal);
    
                }
```

Comment: Sale que se actualizaron porque en el catch del update pusiste eso, quiere decir que hay un error que esta capturando pero tu pusiste un mensaje de todo ok cuando debería ser uno de error como lo es en tu método personal read. Adjunta el mensaje que te sale en consola.

Comment: Ya adjunte el mensaje

Comment: Dale un espacio antes del WHERE en tu query, en: +"'"+"Where idPersonal ="+per.getCodigo());

Comment: sigue sin actualizar

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Insertar datos en MySQL y Java en Eclipse](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36022/insertar-datos-en-mysql-y-java-en-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque estas usando `executeQuery` para un update. Debes usar `executeUpdate` como explica [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36024/3834).

Comment: Ya lo hice pero necesita mas votos

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica aquì:

```
 rs = st.executeQuery("update DPersonal set Dni='"+per.getDNI()+"',NombrePers='"+per.getNombre()+"',ApellidoPers='"+per.getApellido()+
                            "',Edad='"+per.getEdad()+"',Sexo='"+per.getSexo()+"',Direccion='"+per.getDireccion()+"',Celular='"+per.getCelular()+"',Correo='"+per.getCorreo()+"'"+"Where idPersonal ="+per.getCodigo());
```

No debes usar `executeQuery()` para insertar, debes usar [executeUpdate()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-)

Esta serìa la forma de realizarlo, por cierto tienes un detalle en el Query, segura que las palabras reservadas no esten juntas:

```
int registrosModificados = st. executeUpdate("update DPersonal set Dni='"+per.getDNI()+"',NombrePers='"+per.getNombre()+"',ApellidoPers='"+per.getApellido()+
                            "',Edad='"+per.getEdad()+"',Sexo='"+per.getSexo()+"',Direccion='"+per.getDireccion()+"',Celular='"+per.getCelular()+"',Correo='"+per.getCorreo()+"'"+" Where idPersonal ="+per.getCodigo());
```

Como resultado del query de actulizaciòn puedes obtener los elementos modificados.